# C# How do I translate this foreach loop to a for loop

Tags: c#, loops

The statement below returns a price for each item in results. How do I create an array for the returned prices so I can add, subtract, etc. the prices?

```
foreach (SearchItem item in result.item)
{
   Console.WriteLine("Item Converted Price: " + 
                     item.sellingStatus.convertedCurrentPrice.ToString("0.00", 
                     CultureInfo.InvariantCulture));
}
```

Comment: The code you have submitted doesn't `return` anything, it writes it to the stdout. If you can iterate over `result.item`, why do you need to create an array?

Comment: it depends, if it implements IEnumerable<T> (result.item is IEnumerable), then you can call to .ToArray() or .ToList()

Comment: How would I translate this to a for loop as I hear it is better than a foreach loop when iterating over 1000s of strings?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `Linq` expression:

```
result.item.Select(x => item.sellingStatus.convertedCurrentPrice.ToString("0.00", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)).ToArray()
```

But this would create an array of strings, not numerical values.

Comment: How would I translate this to a for loop as I hear it is better than a foreach loop when iterating over 1000s of strings?

Comment: What would you like to translate to `for` loop: `foreach` from your question or `linq` from my answer? I don't really understand your point. Could you please elaborate on this?